# How did Quentin and Laurel Lance know Sara died?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, arrow

When the *Queen's Gambit* went down at sea, Oliver Queen, Robert Queen, and Sara Lance (plus, whatever crew there was) were all presumed dead.

Moira obviously knew that Oliver and Robert were on the boat. Sara, however, was a last minute addition on Oliver's part. As far as we know, other than the people on the boat with them, only

> Dinah Lance

knew Sara was there, and that person didn't tell anyone until after Oliver returned. Instead, the Lance family all believed Sara was away at college (at least, according to her dialog in S02E05, "League of Assassins").

So, how did Laurel and Quentin find out that Sara was dead, and specifically, that she died on the *Queen's Gambit*?

Comment: I feel like I remember someone coming forward and saying they saw Sara get on the boat, and then they just assumed her dead after being missing so long. I may just be confusing it with the mother though.

Comment: Huh. I didn't even catch that, and just assumed someone knew. Good catch, though!

Comment: Dinah wasn't the only one who saw Sara get on the boat.  It's mentioned a few times explicitly that the ship's captain saw Sara boarding, as did the crew and the dock workers.  She didn't exactly sneak onboard, the only person who was at the docks that didn't see her get on, was Laurel.  So it's pretty likely someone mentioned it to someone.  They also could have called friends at her college or the college itself after not hearing from her for a while and discovered that she never returned.  I think it's actually stated to Laurel that someone close saw her getting on the boat and didn't

Comment: stop her.  I'll have to watch again to make sure I'm not lying though.  Basically, they found out she wasn't at school, hadn't seen her, saw no news about her, and probably figured it out by themselves.  Quentin's also a detective, so he probably asked the dock workers when investigating the Gambit after the crash.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the [Arrow & Flash Wiki](http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Moira_Queen), there is a scene in the episode "Heir to the Demon" in which...

> Moira also appears in a flashback sequence, visiting Quentin and Laurel Lance in order to tell them that Sara was on the Queen's Gambit when it sank.

This is during the "Moira keeps too many secrets" arc (which is to say, the entire show).  While I don't specifically remember us seeing Moira learn about Oliver's relationship with Sara, Moira is a tricky dame and has a knack for learning things that no one expected her to learn.

If I find the scene where Moira first discovers Oliver & Sara's relationship on a re-watch, I'll edit this question and add that.

Comment: huh. i didn't remember moira knowing, but that would explain it :)

Comment: The transcript [here](http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=arrow&episode=s02e13) confirms the dialog (speakers are unclear, but it's definitely Moira that fesses up). Search the page for "dock master".

Comment: cool. i was waiting until E13 came up in my queue to accept, but that works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Season 2 Episode 13, "[Heir to the Demon](https://arrow.fandom.com/wiki/Heir_to_the_Demon)".

Flashbacks are all throughout the episode. It goes back six years from the present date, and shows how the Lance family was. With Sara coming back from college, texting Oliver and making plans to jump on the Queen's Gambit. Right at the end of the episode, Moira Queen knocks on the Lances' door and explains that the Dockmaster had seen Sara sneak aboard the Queen's Gambit.

Comment: Given the accepted answer doesn't actually state the episode where this happened, this answer seems valid to me, particularly since the user is low-rep and therefore would have more difficulty in getting an edit to go through.